# Hibernate Post Insert event triggers twice

Tags: java, hibernate, event-listener

I've just implemented a post-insert event listener for my java-spring-hibernate-mysql server. What I want to do is this - each time a new object of a certain type is created, I want to create  series of stats on it. A bit random, but clients want the strangest things. I don't want any future coders to accidentally balls this up, so i thought a post-insert listener would achieve this for me.

here is my app context entry:

```
<property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>post-insert</value>
                </key>
                <list>
                    <bean class="xxx.MyPostInsertEventListener" />
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
```

and this is my class:

```
package au.com.reignite.recursionNesting;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEventListener;

public class MyPostInsertListener implements PostInsertEventListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2377752551659130306L;

@Override
public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {

    // this kicks in once a new record has been inserted. 
    if (event.getEntity() instanceof XXX) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = event.getPersister().getFactory().getCurrentSession();
            // this is the code that does the creations etc
        } catch (HibernateException he) {

            // this catches the situation where the transaction persist fails, and ensures the rollback of the information created in the flat tables
            System.out.println("transaction persist error: " + he.getMessage());
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

}
```

}

but my problem is this: it kicks in twice. I am calling this saveOrUpdate method to persist the object:

```
protected void saveOrUpdate(final Domain domain) {
    final List<Domain> domains = new ArrayList<Domain>();
    domains.add(domain);
    saveOrUpdateAll(domains);
}

protected void saveOrUpdateAll(final Collection<? extends Domain> domains) {
    if (domains != null) {
        for (final Domain domain : domains) {
            if (domain.getId() != null) {
                domain.setModifiedDate(new Date());
            } else {
                domain.setCreatedDate(new Date());
            }
        }
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(domains);
    }
}
```

any ideas on why this may be getting called twice?

thanks for you time,
Margaret

Comment: Did you check that your listener is not recorded twice ? (You can check that by step-by-step debugging in hibernate code... and at some point will see that hibernate iterate over an array of listeners, check this array to see if you don't have 2 instances of MyPostInsertListener in it. - put a breakpoint in your PostInsert method to quickly find the hibernate listener array -

Comment: bingo. thank you! the listeners were configured twice. another developer had added listeners for lucene indexing in another location which i had missed.